# Performing a JOIN with the closest-matching time

Tags: sql, inner-join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

As a simplified scenario, suppose I have the following tables:

deal_views:

```
user_id | viewed_at           | more attributes ...
------------------------------
1       | 2020-07-12 15:00:00 | ...
1       | 2020-07-12 14:00:00 | ...
1       | 2020-07-12 13:00:00 | ...
1       | 2020-07-03 09:00:00 | ...
2       | 2020-07-12 15:00:00 | ...
2       | 2020-07-12 14:00:00 | ...
2       | 2020-07-12 13:00:00 | ...
3       | 2020-07-12 15:00:00 | ...
```

purchases:

```
user_id | purchased_at        | more attributes ...
------------------------------
1       | 2020-07-03 09:02:10 | ...
1       | 2020-07-12 14:04:53 | ...
2       | 2020-07-12 15:20:12 | ...
```

(Not every user who views the deals will make a purchase; some users will view deals multiple times before making a purchase; some users will make multiple purchases. Every user who made a purchase must have viewed the deals at least once; probably just before the purchase!)

What I want is a selection of `deal_views` (including some additional attributes; omitted above for simplicity) that occurred *most recently before a purchase*, for each user. The motivation here is that the visible deals *change* over time, so we'd like to know "what was the state of the deals, most recently before a purchase?".

So for the data above, this would be:

```
user_id | viewed_at           | more attributes ...
------------------------------
1       | 2020-07-03 09:00:00 | ...
1       | 2020-07-11 14:00:00 | ...
2       | 2020-07-11 15:00:00 | ...
```

SQL performance would be nice, but it's not a huge concern (so long as it's runnable!) as this is only a one-off query I wish to execute. There should be approximately 200,000 rows in the results table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Snowflake supports lateral joins, so you can do:

```
select p.*, d.*
from purchases p left join lateral
     (select d.*
      from deals d
      where d.user_id = p.user_id and
            d.viewed_at < p.purchased_at
      order by d.viewed_at desc
      limit 1
     ) d
     on 1=1;
```

You can also `row_number()`:

```
select pd.*
from (select p.*, d.*,   -- select the columns explicitly to avoid duplicate column names
            row_number() over (partition by p.user_id, p.purchased_at order by d.viewed_at desc) as seqnum
      from purchases p left join
           deals d
           on d.user_id = p.user_id and d.viewed_at < p.purchased_at 
     ) pd
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: I couldn't get the lateral join to work (although it may well have been something I was doing wrong on my significantly-more-complex setup), but the `row_number()` (window function) worked a treat. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score -1):

(*Disclaimer:* I don't have Snowflake so I haven't tried or tested. I tested it on MS SQL.)

```
/*
DECLARE @deal_views AS TABLE (
    id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), 
    [user_id] INT NOT NULL,
    viewed_at DATETIME NOT NULL);

DECLARE @purchases AS TABLE (
    id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), 
    [user_id] INT NOT NULL,
    purchased_at DATETIME NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO @deal_views VALUES
    (1, '2020-07-12 15:00:00'), (1, '2020-07-12 14:00:00'), (1, '2020-07-12 13:00:00'),
    (1, '2020-07-03 09:00:00'),
    (2, '2020-07-12 15:00:00'), (2, '2020-07-12 14:00:00'), (2, '2020-07-12 13:00:00'),
    (3, '2020-07-12 15:00:00')

INSERT INTO @purchases VALUES
    (1, '2020-07-03 09:02:10'),
    (1, '2020-07-12 14:04:53'),
    (2, '2020-07-12 15:20:12')*/

SELECT p.[user_id], MAX(d.viewed_at) AS viewed_at
FROM purchases p
JOIN deal_views d
    ON  p.[user_id] = d.[user_id]
    AND p.purchased_at > d.viewed_at
GROUP BY p.[user_id], p.purchased_at
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]

*[DB Fiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cb1d7bedfe9d21634d41c20e65a37532)*

If you need other attributes from deal_views, join it back with the deal view.

```
SELECT d.id,
       d.user_id,
       d.viewed_at,
       d.attributes2, d.attributes3, d.attributes4
FROM (
    SELECT p.[user_id], MAX(d.viewed_at) AS viewed_at
    FROM purchases p
    JOIN deal_views d
        ON  p.[user_id] = d.[user_id]
        AND p.purchased_at > d.viewed_at
    GROUP BY p.[user_id], p.purchased_at) mv
JOIN deal_views d
    ON  mv.[user_id] = d.[user_id]
    AND mv.viewed_at > d.viewed_at
```